# How to use Atk.Relation in Python

Tags: python, pygobject, gobject

i am trying to migrate an application from gtk2 to gtk3 using GObject Introspection (`gi.repository`).

The problem i have now is creating an `Atk.Relation` in an accessibility method that looks like this:

```python
from gi.repository import Atk

def atk_acc(obj, lbl):

    atk_obj = obj.get_accessible()
    atk_l = lbl.get_accessible()

    relation_set = atk_l.ref_relation_set()
    relation = Atk.Relation.new([atk_obj], 1, Atk.RelationType.LABEL_FOR)
    relation_set.add(relation)
```

When i run the application, it breaks with an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/erick/Desarrollo/git/canaima-instalador/canaimainstalador/main.py", line 237, in siguiente
    CFG['w'].next('Metodo', Metodo, (CFG), PasoMetodo(CFG))
  File "/home/erick/Desarrollo/git/canaima-instalador/canaimainstalador/pasos/metodo.py", line 63, in __init__
    atk_acc(self.cmb_discos, self.lbl1)
  File "/home/erick/Desarrollo/git/canaima-instalador/canaimainstalador/mod_accesible.py", line 37, in atk_acc
    relation = Atk.Relation.new([atk_obj], 1, Atk.RelationType.LABEL_FOR)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 72, in constructor
    return info.invoke(cls, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: Expected Atk.Object, but got GObjectMeta
```

In [ATK documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/atk/unstable/AtkRelation.html#atk-relation-new) says that the first argument of `Atk.Relation.new` is an array.

What i'm doing wrong here?